Find $\lim_{x\to\infty}\left(\sqrt{\frac{1-x^4}{2x-x^2}}-\sqrt{\frac{2x^4}{1+2x^2}}\right)$
$$\lim_{x\to\infty}\left(\sqrt{\frac{1-x^4}{2x-x^2}}-\sqrt{\frac{2x^4}{1+2x^2}}\right)$$
How would I solve this? I tried multiplying with the changed sign so it becomes $a^2 - b^2$ but I can't still figure it out.
Edit. I did $$\lim_{x\to\infty}\left(\sqrt{\frac{1-x^4}{2x-x^2}}-\sqrt{\frac{2x^4}{1+2x^2}}\right)\times \frac{\sqrt{\frac{1-x^4}{2x-x^2}}+\sqrt{\frac{2x^4}{1+2x^2}}}{\sqrt{\frac{1-x^4}{2x-x^2}}+\sqrt{\frac{2x^4}{1+2x^2}}}$$ but the denominator is still problematic.

Can you show your work on that?

Could you answer how you solved it for future viewers?

As an alternative, we have that
$$\sqrt{\frac{1-x^4}{2x-x^2}}-\sqrt{\frac{2x^4}{1+2x^2}}=x\left(\sqrt{\frac{1-\frac1{x^4}}{1-\frac2x}}-\sqrt{\frac{1}{1+\frac 1{2x^2}}}\right)$$
and as $t=\frac1 x \to 0$ we can use that $(1+t)^{a}=1+at+o(t)$ to obtain
$$\frac1t \left[\left(1+o(t)\right)\left(1+t+o(t)\right)-(1+o(t)\right]=\frac1t\left(t+o(t)\right)=1+o(1) \to 1$$

Another method
$$A=\lim_{x\to\infty}\left(\sqrt{\frac{1-x^4}{2x-x^2}}-\sqrt{\frac{2x^4}{1+2x^2}}\right)\times \frac{\sqrt{\frac{1-x^4}{2x-x^2}}+\sqrt{\frac{2x^4}{1+2x^2}}}{\sqrt{\frac{1-x^4}{2x-x^2}}+\sqrt{\frac{2x^4}{1+2x^2}}}$$
$$A=\lim_{x\to\infty} \displaystyle\frac{{\frac{1-x^4}{2x-x^2}}-{\frac{2x^4}{1+2x^2}}}{\sqrt{\frac{1-x^4}{2x-x^2}}+\sqrt{\frac{2x^4}{1+2x^2}}}$$
$$A=\lim_{x\to\infty} \displaystyle\frac{\frac{4x^5+x^4-2x^2-1}{(x-2)(2x^2+1)x}}{\sqrt{\frac{1-x^4}{2x-x^2}}+\sqrt{\frac{2x^4}{1+2x^2}}}$$
Now we will do some approximations. Observe that as $x\to\infty$ the numerator of the expression goes to $2x$ while the denominator goes to $x+x$. We can find this by factoring out the highest power of $x$ from both the numerator and denominator of a term.
Hence, $$A=\frac{2x}{2x}$$
$$\boxed{A=1}$$

This is not a valid argument. By your "approximation" reasoning, what is $\lim\limits_{x\to\infty} \left(\sqrt{x^2+x} - \sqrt{x^2+1}\right)$?

@TedShifrin maybe i phrased it incorrectly, but what i am essentialy doing is factoring out thr highest power of x from each term (from both the numerator and denominator). i do this process to all of the terms collectively but just for the sake of explanation, i wrote that i do this process one by one (first to the numerator and then to the denominator)

@TedShifrin and answer to that limit is 1/2

@TedShifrin  $$A=\lim\limits_{x\to\infty} \left(\sqrt{x^2+x} - \sqrt{x^2+1}\right)$$ $$A=\lim\limits_{x\to\infty}\frac{{x^2+x} - {x^2-1}}{\sqrt{x^2+x} + \sqrt{x^2+1}}$$  $$A=\lim\limits_{x\to\infty}\frac{x\left(1-\frac{1}{x}\right)}{x\left(\sqrt{1+\frac{1}{x}}+\sqrt{1+\frac{1}{x^2}}\right)}$$ $$A=\frac{x}{2x}=\frac{1}{2}$$

My point is that just analyzing leading terms is not always sufficient and requires more subtle justification. When you do approximations, you must show that the error is in fact insignificant. What is the asymptote, for example, of $f(x)=x^{1/3}(1-x)^{2/3}$?

@TedShifrin is my solution correct??

@TedShifrin i mean, isnt that obvious?? like the error that we get is infinitesimal as $\frac{1}{x}$ or $\frac{1}{x^2}$ goes to $0$ as $x\to\infty$

Ted's point is that you can't analyze the dominating term and conclude the denominator behaves like $2x$; you have to first see if the part you neglect is $o(x)$

@TedShifrin i think the function  you gave me has no asymptotes

@SineoftheTime i havent learnt time complexity yet...i do not understand the big O and the small O notations comfortably

@SineoftheTime my teacher (from whom i learnt calculus) didnt tell me that if i have to neglect something then it must be $o(x)$

I'd say that your argument here it's fine since, after factoring the highest powers, you get $2x(1+\text{rubbish})$

@SineoftheTime exactly...this is how i was taught...just like this..you understand me too well☺️

Oh, it definitely has an asymptote of the form $y=ax+b$.

@TedShifrin are a and b real numbers?

To avoid confusion, you can do this step $$\frac{\frac{4x^5+x^4-2x^2-1}{(x-2)(2x^2+1)x}}{\sqrt{\frac{1-x^4}{2x-x^2}}+\sqrt{\frac{2x^4}{1+2x^2}}}=\frac{\frac{4+1/x-2/x^3-1/x^5}{(1-2/x)(2+1/x^2)}}{\sqrt{\frac{1-1/x^4}{1-2/x}}+\sqrt{\frac{1}{1+1/(2x^2)}}}\to \frac 2 2 =1$$
